# New OS SSD - unable to boot with it

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, ssd, paragon

Yesterday I connected my new 240GB SSD disk which is meant to replace my old 60GB SSD, which is my current OS disk.

I used "Paragon Migrate OS to SSD" to copy the OS (Windows 8) from the 60GB disk to the 240GB disk, which went smooth. However, when I tried changing the boot sequence, it still seems like it's booting into the old 60GB SSD (which still has the OS on it). I tried unconnect the 60GB disk physically, and force it into the 240GB disk, but then I only got a system repair message - which is not quite what I wanted.

I didn't manage to find any good solutions. Is there anything else I have to fix? Bootmgr/setting boot disk in Disk Management or similar?

**Disk management**

[image: manager]

I just want the Disk 2 to be the boot one, and not require a system repair...

Comment: Ah - I forgot to write it in the text.. It's Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: I noticed the tag and deleted the comment just before you posted

Answer (score 0):

Try running the startup repair with your old disk disconnected. All it should do is set the new disk to bootable.

Comment: Alright, then I'll try! After that, I could simply format the current C: drive into another letter, and make the new disk the new C:?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, I've used the startup repair many times when imaging win 7 it works very well.

Comment: Hm, tried creating a Windows 8 system repair disk through an USB, but after starting it up (without the old SSD connected), it seems like it's unable to actually fix anything with automatic repair, it just boots up with the same error: 0xc000000e (important device not connected, or similar error).

Comment: I just had a quick read of the Paragon manual, have you created a winpe recovery media? That looks like it has some tools for repairing boot issues.  The section I was looking at in the manual is titled "Correcting the boot configuration data"

Comment: No, I tried creating a Windows System Repair USB device. I'm not able to create a WinPE recovery media, the application only gives me an "Error code 18, cannot copy file" error. I'll have to check it out.